# Given the matrices $A\in M_{m\times n}, B\in M_{n\times p}: \ B\neq 0$, suppose $AB=0$. Prove: there exists a non-trivial solution for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, solution-verification

Given two matrices: $A_{m\times n}$ and  $B_{n\times p}$, such that $B\neq 0$,
suppose $AB=0$.

**Prove:** there exists a non-trivial solution for $Ax=0$.

*My Attempt:*

suppose by contradiction that the only solution for the linear equation system $Ax=0$ is the trivial solution, meaning $Ax=0 \iff x=0$.

$$Ax=0\Longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
a_{m1} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{array}\right]$$

Hence, $$\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}+\cdots+a_{1n}x_{n}=0\\
a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}+\cdots+a_{2n}x_{n}=0\\
\cdots\\
a_{m1}x_{1}+a_{m2}x_{2}+\cdots+a_{mn}x_{n}=0
\end{array}\right]$$

According to the assumption: $x_{1}=x_{2}=\cdots=x_{n}=0$

Now, Let $B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & b_{1p}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
b_{n1} & \cdots & \cdots & b_{np}
\end{array}\right]$

Let $AB=(t)_{ij}$, as $\begin{array}{c}
1\le i\le m\\
1\le j\le p
\end{array}$

$AB=0\Longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
a_{m1} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & b_{1p}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
b_{n1} & \cdots & \cdots & b_{np}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\cdots\\
\cdots\\
0
\end{array}\right]$

$\Longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11}b_{11}+\cdots+a_{1n}b_{n1}\  & \cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots & a_{11}b_{1p}+\cdots+a_{1n}b_{np}\\
\cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots\\
\cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots & \cdots\cdots\\
a_{m1}b_{11}+\cdots+a_{mn}b_{n1}\  & \cdots\cdots\  & \cdots\cdots\  & a_{m1}b_{1p}+\cdots+a_{mn}b_{np}
\end{array}\right]$

This means that for every $i,j:\ t{}_{ij}=0$, therefore $$\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}b_{11}+\cdots+a_{1n}b_{n1}=a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}+\cdots+a_{1n}x_{n}=0\\
\cdots\cdots\\
a_{m1}b_{11}+\cdots+a_{mn}b_{n1}=a_{m1}x_{1}+a_{m2}x_{2}+\cdots+a_{mn}x_{n}=0
\end{array}$$

but $x_{1}=\cdots=x_{n}=0$, then  $b_{11}=\cdots=b_{n1}=0$.

this equity applies for every column of $B$, consequently, $B=0$.

But that's a contradiction to the fact that 
$B\neq 0$, then we'll get a contradiction to the assumption, therefore there exists a non-trivial solution for 
$Ax=0$, as wished.

It this correct?

Comment: A style point: This isn't really a proof by contradiction.  It's a proof by *contrapositive* where you have assumed the negation of your conclusion and proven the negation of one of your hypotheses.  But really, the direct proof that Nicolas outlines is much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $B = [b_1,...,b_p] \neq 0$, there is some $i \in \{1,...,p\}$ such that $b_i \neq 0$. Then, by definition of the matrix product, $Ab_i = 0$.